# Visual Studio 2017 Publish Targets Azure App Service Linux Instead of Azure App Service

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2017

We are experimenting with the templates created here: http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2016/10/04/angular2-template-for-visual-studio/.  However when we open in Visual Studio 2017 and select publish we are presented with only a Linux App Service:

[image]

Instead of:

[image]

Can anyone explain what configuration is causing this to happen, as the only option is the Linux preview existing app services we have in Azure are not available to be selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's the presence of the Dockerfile. If you close the Publish UI, delete the Dockerfile, and reopen the Publish UI, it will show the non-Linux App Service option. See [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/11/16/new-docker-tools-for-visual-studio/) for a little bit of info.